# How to Change Input type of Textfield and allow only Hexadecimal input at the same time in android?

Tags: android, hex, android-textinputedittext

I have an input field (EditText) which have input type (android:inputType="number") when the applicaton runs.My queston is that i have a checkbox in my app(android) as well so i want that when that checkbox is get checked so the input type of the textfield is change to Text and only take Hexadecimal Numbers from user

Comment: Hi, do you have any code we can reproduce? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is used when InputType is android:inputType="number" to allow only 0 & 1 as user input ( et1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("01")); ).Now is the anything like this when the inputtype is change to Text.......Like et1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFf"));

Comment: if(rd1.isChecked()
         //allow only binary
         et1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(" 0 1 "));//Number
      else if(rd2.isChecked())
        //allow only octal
        et1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(" 01234567 "));
      else if(rd3.isChecked())
        //allow only decimal
        et1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
      else if (rd4.isChecked())
        //Nowallow only hexadecimal??
        et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);